# Which one is right preposition for Welcoming someone. "Welcome to home" vs "Welcome at home"

Tags: prepositions

I just argued with my cousin that he claims, it can be used like "Welcome at home" but I know that Welcoming someone has a movement situation so it can not be "Welcome at home" but may "Welcome to home".

So any explanation would be appriciated.

Comment: The most natural would be simply **Welcome home** (if they are returning to their own home).

Answer (score 2):

The most common preposition is *'to'*
**“welcome to”**

*Welcome to our meeting or Milan or whatever*.

**“Welcome at”** is possible in a sentence such as “welcome at the opening of this new studio/gallery” but as said before would be just as correct to say *“Welcome to the opening of this new studios/gallery.“*

You can check this [*link*](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-verb/welcome-to-by-in-into-with/#:%7E:text=They%20are%20all%20welcome%20in,and%20surgeons%20rarely%20moved%20there) for more information and examples about other preposition of *welcome*.

Answer (score 1):

These have different meanings.

If you want to say that there is a pleasant environment for a person at their home you can say that they are "welcome at home." This would mean that when they are home the other people treat them well and are pleasant.

If you meet somebody at the door of your home you might say "welcome to my home." This means you are trying to be pleasant and polite to them.

The exact phrase "welcome to home" is probably incomplete. You want "welcome to my home" when you invite somebody in. Or "welcome to your home" if you were a real estate agent giving the keys to somebody who had just bought a new house.

If there was a place called Home (as there was in the movie "A Clockwork Orange") then you might say "welcome to Home."  But that's similar to "welcome to Balmoral" which a tour guide might say as they started the tour of [Balmoral Castle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmoral_Castle)